# Jquery UI Autocomplete muiltiple results

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

Morning

So I have a input search box that will look up address data.

result shown in list first input box
e.g. LL1 1AA - 16 Addresses Found

I then want to be able to click the option above to show the 16 addresses in separate lines
e.g  1 the street LL1 1AA, 2 the street LL1 1AA

Currently After the user clicks the search result in the first list I have:
$("#id").autocomplete( "search", search_term);

which doesn't then give me the second list

but it does work if I switch out the input fields but not on same input field.

any suggestions?